# Science Fiction Book from the 80's about a group with Psychic powers

Tags: story-identification

I remember that one of the main characters was a researcher into psychic abilities.  He went to a remote Scottish location following reports of a girl with special abilities and found her, living like an animal because she was so overwhelmed by hearing everyone's thoughts.  He helped her gain control of her powers using sensory deprivation.  He also developed abilities, and so did several other people that joined their team.  There was a Russian boy was had been kept in a sensory deprivation tank since birth.  There were several references to synesthesia (like smelling the color purple).

I would love to find the book again, but can't remember the name. I thought it was called "The Harrowing" but a Google search for that doesn't turn up anything useful.

Comment: Good luck. Feel free to also check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if that helps jog your memory.

Answer (score 4):

It was indeed called **"The Harrowing" by Ainslie Skinner**.

https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/ainslie-skinner/the-harrowing-2/

> When neurologist Philip Elliot endures a car accident and eight-day coma, he comes out of it able--naturally--to read minds. Discomforted by this for years, he at last transfers from neurosurgery to an ESP research center near London which seeks ""the inevitable evolutionary refining of the brain."" And when he decides to vacation on a Scottish isle with a haunted cottage, Elliot is barely indoors before he's violently invaded by the invisible spirit. . . which turns out to be not a ghost but ESP waves from Annie Craigie, an autistic adult ""wild child"" whose paranormal abilities dwarf Elliot's.

and something else which matches what you remember:

> In fact, not only do the Russians have an out-of-body spy who has been kept in a sensory deprivation tank for nine years

Comment: I would have suggested that the book was called 'Minds Eye' but after a spot of googleing it looks like the same book was released with two different titles.